# Drush sql-sync not placing file in specified dump-dir

Tags: drush

I have a dev and staging alias setup for drush and they are both working correctly. I included a reference to where I want the dump file placed during a `drush sql-sync` using

```
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%dump-dir' => '/home/.drush/db_dumps'
  )
```

However, when I run the command it runs successfully but it doesn't use my dump directory. Instead it uses */home/user/drush-backups*. I tried changing the location of my dump-dir to a location inside of the drupal site folder, but it still doesn't work.

One of the solutions that I found was to include the `--source-dump` option (which points to the same location as I have in `%dump-dir`) when running `drush sql-sync`. It seems like if that's the case, then why even bother adding it in my alias file.

Another solution states to also include a reference to the actual dump file using `%dump`in the path-aliases array. I tried that and it still doesn't work.

Is there a solution to this or is it not suppose to work at all?? Because the example.aliases.drushrc.php file doesn't mention dump-dir at all.

Using: 
Ubuntu 14.0.4,
Drush 8.0.5,
Drupal 8 site

Thanx

Comment: Haven't tried to reproduce this, but looks like it could be a bug in Drush 8.0.5.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson I would have to dig, but I'm pretty sure this was a bug in Drush 6 that I submitted a PR for that got merged.  It's possible that there was a regression.

Comment: @MPD sql-sync was rewritten in Drush 7; may have been re-introduced there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually posted the same question in the Drush GitHub and they did in fact tell me that `sql-sync` was rewritten (removed in [`e89c7c4`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/commit/e89c7c44d849643c5b50f0d51153495b2a46e65d)) and it no longer includes the option for a `dump-dir`.

As per [GH #2125](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2125#issuecomment-207813193), they've said:

> It gzips and transfers the full dump every time. It uses a temp file in your specified temp dir for the transfer. Files are deleted right after rsync.

So I guess all documentation that is out there is old.